Best Ways to Understand CPI Implementation on Solana Other than Official Docs?
I’m currently learning about Cross-Program Invocations (CPIs) in Solana, and while the official documentation is helpful, I find myself looking for additional resources and practical examples to deepen my understanding.
Are there any other learning materials, blog posts, tutorials, or real-world examples that provide a clearer or alternative perspective on how CPIs are implemented in Solana?
I’d particularly appreciate:
Code examples demonstrating CPIs in action.
In-depth explanations or use cases of CPIs.
Insights from experienced developers or lessons learned from working with CPIs in production.
Looking forward to your suggestions!

Cross Program Invocations allow you to call instructions for another program inside your program.
For example, suppose you wanted to call the Raydium CPMM program from your program. You would do so using a CPI into the Raydim program.
Since the runtime needs to know about the accounts you are going to interact with beforehand, you are going to include all the accounts that are required for raydium in your ix and any additional accounts that you might make use of in your instruction.
Some additional resources

https://www.rareskills.io/post/cross-program-invocation
https://www.anchor-lang.com/docs/cross-program-invocations

practical examples

raydium CPI examples

